# Clean solution to ensure a singleton service is created on app initialization

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to ensure a singleton service is created on application boot. I could add it as injection parameter to my AppComponent and not use it at all, but that looks a bit *dirty*. Right now I'm going with this solution:

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationService } from './navigation.service';

@NgModule()
export class NavigationServiceModule {
    public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<NavigationServiceModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: NavigationServiceModule,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
                    deps: [NavigationService],
                    multi: true,
                    useFactory: () => () => { }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But don't really love it, too. Any ideas how this could be achieved best?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the default service setup and don't add it to the `providers` array - only one instance will be created (unless you explicitly provide it outside of constructors)

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavigationService
```

Comment: But that won't trigger it's constructor until it's used. I want to ensure it is started with the application (e.g. to log all router NavigationEnds)

Comment: Using an empty function? Just want it to behave like a module extending an application, nur like a service that needs to be injected "for some reason" ... So you'd take the APP_INITIALIZER?